# How to get the height for each column in Python?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

This is a nested list:

```
matrix = [['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0'],
          ['0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
          ['0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0'],
          ['0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1'],
          ['0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0'],
          ['0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0'],
          ['0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1'],
          ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1']]
#output should be [1,2,2,2,3,1,5,3,4,2]

Height = 8
Width = 10
```

I want to know how I can get the height of each column. And then each height, I want to put it in a list.

We counting 1's and they only count for the height if they are adjoint 1's.

We start with counting below and then go up.

Output should be `[1,2,2,2,3,1,5,3,4,1]`

I only want to use build in Python functions.

I tried with a for loop and if, else statements.

```
For loop iterate through the list.
like if i == '1' add 1 to counter.
if i == '0' reset counter and add the last value from counter to counter1, but only if counter is greater then counter1.
```

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: Please edit your question to include what you have tried

Comment: Why is the height of the last column supposed to be 1?

Comment: Last column shoul be 2 (i guess)

Comment: Yeah just edited

Comment: Well the things I tried were with a for loop and if, else statements. Like for loop iterate through the list and if i were a '1', counter 1 added 1

Comment: what do you mean by "if they are adjoint 1's" ?

Comment: 1's above each other, without a 0 interfering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.takewhile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile) on the reversed, zipped matrix:

```
from itertools import takewhile
out = [len(list(takewhile(lambda x: x=='1', reversed(l)))) for l in zip(*matrix)]
```

output:

```
[1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 5, 3, 4, 2]
```

If you don't want to import `takewhile`, use the recipe:

```
def takewhile(predicate, iterable):
    # takewhile(lambda x: x<5, [1,4,6,4,1]) --> 1 4
    for x in iterable:
        if predicate(x):
            yield x
        else:
            break
```

#### How it works:

`zip` rotates the matrix:

```
>>> list(zip(*matrix))

[('0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1'),
 ('0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1'),
 ('0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1'),
 ('0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1'),
 ('0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1'),
 ('1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1'),
 ('1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1'),
 ('0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1'),
 ('0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1'),
 ('0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1')]
```

The list comprehension with `reversed` rotates the other way around (actually inverses each row):

```
>>> [list(reversed(l)) for l in zip(*matrix)]

[['1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
 ['1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0'],
 ['1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0'],
 ['1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0'],
 ['1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0'],
 ['1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1'],
 ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1'],
 ['1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0'],
 ['1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0'],
 ['1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0']]
```

`takewhile` keepd the elements while the condition is True, here while the items are `'1'` (`lambda x: x=='1'`), and `len` gets the length of the output:

```
>>> l = ['1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0']
>>> list(takewhile(lambda x: x=='1', l))

['1', '1', '1']

>>> len(list(takewhile(lambda x: x=='1', l)))
3
```

*NB. functions like `zip`, `reversed`, `takewhile` are generators, they don't produce output unless something consumes it, that's why I used `list(generator(…))` in the exammples*

##### solution with classical python loops:

```
out = []
for l in zip(*matrix):
    counter = 0
    for elem in reversed(l):
        if elem == '1':
            counter +=1
        else:
            break
    out.append(counter)
```

Comment: This is good solution, I only don't know what takewhile and zip does + I don't understand lambda's completely, so I have to look it up. I also want to understand what is does :)

Comment: @CaptainGuan I added details

Comment: Cool many Thanks